# Getting Thumbnail id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get Thumbnail and full size images from custume post type.

Can anyone help me with how I can get the the title of image and thumbnail id in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, false );
    }
}

?>
Try this hope it's help for you
```

Comment: Thanx for reply @navnit